# set Bootstrap progressbar dynamically

Tags: php

I'd like to know how I can set a Bootstrap progressbar width dynamically.
Let's assume I have a php file like this

```
$server_maxclients = 5; // dynamic 
$server_clientsonline = 1 // dynamic
```

now if I want to create a progress bar for that I would do

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $server_clientsonline; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="<?php echo $server_maxclients; ?>" style="background-color: #4ba84b;width: 20%;"></div>
```

20% because 100%/5 = 20%, but what do I do? When I have for example:

```
$server_clientsonline = 4;
$server_maxclients = 50;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct logic for getting percentage is:-

```
<?php echo ($server_clientsonline*100/$server_maxclients).'%';?>
```

You need to use this code directly into `style` as well as you have to give some `height` to the `div` to make it visible.

Do like below:-

```
<div 
    class="progress-bar" 
    role="progressbar" 
    aria-valuenow="<?php echo $server_clientsonline; ?>" 
    aria-valuemin="0" 
    aria-valuemax="<?php echo $server_maxclients; ?>" 
    style="background-color: #4ba84b;width: <?php echo ($server_clientsonline*100/$server_maxclients).'%';?>; height:30px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciated

Comment: @floreich  glad to help you :):)